# Writing into csv files using python

Tags: python

Guys I was trying to write into a csv file using python and the code I used for it is as follows

```
        with open(csvfile,'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

so after this when I tried to use this code

```
with open(filename,'r') as csvfile:
    csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvFileReader:
        dates.append(int(row[0]))
        prices.append(float(row[1]))
```

I get an error as *IndexError: list index out of range* 
I checked the file and found that there is an empty line created after every write that has been performed. Is that the cause of this error? If so how can I rectify it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use print-statements to help you identify where things break. Debug it in other words.

Comment: Among other things, follow [the `csv` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3); both `open` calls should be passing `newline=''` to disable line ending translation (so the `csv` module is the sole arbiter of correct line endings). Per the docs: "If `csvfile` is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether row is empty or not by adding `print (row)`.
If you check that row is empty, you can pass it by many ways.
Such as, `if len(row) == 0: continue;`.

Comment: Nitpick: Faster/simpler to follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false." `if not row:` is the preferred test.